# Зачем нужны статические методы и свойства?

Tags: php

Искал много ответов на данный вопрос, но не нашёл не единого ответа, чтобы я что-то понял.

Для чего используется статические методы, свойства? Почему просто не использовать обычные методы, по вызову через объект?

Я знаю только один плюс в этих статических методов - это то, что их можно вызывать напрямую через класс, не создавая экземпляр.

Так же, я нашел вот такой пример, но все равно не понял. Тут описано отличие, но ведь можно написать такой же код, но без interface - [статья](https://klisl.com/php_Interface.html)

Так же, мой вопрос по interface, тут дела по хуже, я вообще не понимаю, для чего он нужен, ведь код можно написать без него и работать будет так же, а на написание этого interface уйдёт лишнее время. Объясните пожалуйста по буквам, дабы я понял это все.

Comment: по интерфейсам https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.f07620e4-62f31a77-927b690f-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/20463/what-is-the-point-of-interfaces-in-php), либо иные страницы с гугла..вроде все понятно жеж. По статик методам и св-вам в доке расписано (ниже дали ссылку)

Comment: Обычно наоборот все хейтят динамику и используют статику. Просто удобнее

Answer (score 0):

1. Да, по статическим свойствам и методам польза именно в том, что не нужно создавать объекты. Это может быть нужно, когда объект класса может быть только один (`Singleton`), либо просто для работы с какими-то вещами, где не требуется хранить состояние объекта, а просто нужно пользоваться какими-то методами. Я не знаю какие есть библиотеки конкретно у `PHP`, но допустим вам нужна функция синус и она лежит в каком-то классе. Зачем создавать объект и тратить память, если от объекта вам нужен только метод, правильно? Вот вы и вызываете метод подсчёта синуса, не создавая объект, а просто вызываете статический метод класса. Или вы хотите скачать страницу в интернете. Или сделать или подсчитать что-то ещё, что не требует хранения состояния, а просто получает что-то на вход и даёт что-то на выходе - в этом случае статический метод очень кстати.
2. Интерфейс - это, как сейчас модно говорить, **контракт**. "Я обязуюсь делать то-то". Класс, реализующий контракт, обязуется уметь выполнять какие-то методы. Чем это полезно? Другой класс, который пользуется этими методами, при работе через интерфейс, может ничего не знать про класс, реализующий этот интерфейс. Вы легко можете переделывать этот класс или заменять его на другой - для класса, пользующегося интерфейсом, ничего не поменяется. Всё, что он знает - это что он пользуется классом, реализующим такой-то интерфейс. Не нужно жёстко прошивать в коде зависимость от конкретного класса. Проще тестировать класс - нужно протестировать только те методы, которые реализует интерфейс, а не все методы класса, работа которых по отдельности вполне может меняться и может быть не регламентирована.

Answer (score -1):

Это все упрощает жизнь в дальнейшем, тебе или другому разработчику. Интерфейс это как правило, которому следует придерживаться при написании класса. По статическим классам могу дать только ссылку, вроде все понятно описано
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.static.php